# The image in firebase notification in Flutter is not displaying in the devices

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a function named sendNotificationToAll(String title, String description, String imageUrl) in which i am passing a title, description, image Url. The title and descriptions are coming in the notification but the image is not coming what might the issue ? The code for the function is given below.

```
  void sendNotificationToAll(
      String title, String description, String imageUrl) async {
    try {
      final url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

      // Fetch all FCM tokens from Firestore or wherever you store them
      QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> usersSnapshot =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User_Information').get();
      print(usersSnapshot);
      List<String> allTokens =
          usersSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc['FCM Tocken'] as String).toList();
      print(allTokens);

      for (String token in allTokens) {
        // Construct the FCM payload
        Map<String, dynamic> payload = {
          'notification': {
            'title': title,
            'body': description,
          },
          'data': {
            'image': imageUrl,
          },
          'to': token,
        };
        print('$title , $description, $imageUrl');

        // Convert payload to JSON
        String payloadJson = jsonEncode(payload);

        // Make a POST request to FCM endpoint
        final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(url),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':
                'key=AAAAz9C6upw:APA91bHOuq3xb086O8hFxygVKID99HqB_3_z-0n4JJgzW4iy8TE0Nw-oP7tyLemPfBOQdCnkukgexlAzGFjY9-VqXCNurZiq6b-bf80eMcCslg--PEX-LL5yILj49xcMjqQXyHNjxw_L', // Replace with your server key
          },
          body: payloadJson,
        );

        // Check the response
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          print('Notification sent to successfully');
        } else {
          print(
              'Failed to send notification to $token. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
        }
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Notification sent successfully to all Users'),
            duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending notification to all users: $e');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
  'notification': {
        'title': title,
        'body': description,
      },
      'data': {
        'image': imageUrl,
      },
```

add 'image':imageUrl into the notification part

```
'notification': {
        'title': title,
        'body': description,
        'image': imageUrl,
      },
```